# Hollerith data statements

Tags: fortran

The below refers to fortran 66 code.  Trying to recompile very old programs.  Cannot understand the reason for the error.  Need work around recommendations.  trying not to recode in updated fortran.

```
    DATA NPOP/6HPOPS-I,6HPOPS-D,6HPOPS-C,6HPOPS-A,6HPOPS-E,6HPOP-S /
               ^
Truncating characters on right side of hollerith constant at (^) azthree.for:24:
    DATA NPOP/6HPOPS-I,6HPOPS-D,6HPOPS-C,6HPOPS-A,6HPOPS-E,6HPOP-S /
                        ^
Truncating characters on right side of hollerith constant at (^) azthree.for:24:
    DATA NPOP/6HPOPS-I,6HPOPS-D,6HPOPS-C,6HPOPS-A,6HPOPS-E,6HPOP-S /
                                 ^
```

Comment: Show your more complete code, complete error messages and your command you use when compiling (including the compiler version). Please do read the Help page of this site to find out how to ask a good question.

Comment: I suspect this is coming from the old practice of storing strings in integers. Even more fun the code looks to be specific to a system with 6 byte integers.  I think there is no work around except obviously to fix the declaration of `npop` to `character*6 npop(6)` or equivalent. (you can probably leave the hollerith form alone if it makes you happy)

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Fortran66, but Hollerith constants declare the next characters as data, not code. So `6H` would mean something like: The 6 characters after the `H` are supposed to be data, not code.

In essence, I would think that `6HPOPS-I` would be the same as `"POPS-I"`.

Maybe if you could give us the declaration of `NPOP` that would help to understand the issue.

I have kind of recreated the error message with this code:

```
      PROGRAM holl
      IMPLICIT NONE
      CHARACTER*1 NPOP(6)
      INTEGER i
      DATA NPOP / 6HPOPS-I,6HPOPS-D,6HPOPS-C,
     +            6HPOPS-A,6HPOPS-E,6HPOP-S /
      DO 100 i = 1, 6
      PRINT *, NPOP(i)
 100  CONTINUE
      END PROGRAM
```

This gives the compiler warnings:

```
$ gfortran -o holl holl.f
holl.f:6.38:

     +            6HPOPS-A,6HPOPS-E,6HPOP-S /
                                      1
Warning: Legacy Extension: Hollerith constant at (1)
holl.f:5.20:

      DATA NPOP / 6HPOPS-I,6HPOPS-D,6HPOPS-C,
                    1
Warning: Initialization string starting at (1) was truncated to fit the variable (1/6)
holl.f:5.29:

      DATA NPOP / 6HPOPS-I,6HPOPS-D,6HPOPS-C,
                             1
Warning: Initialization string starting at (1) was truncated to fit the variable (1/6)
```

But it's not quite your errors. I don't know which compiler you use, and in your case, the marker for the truncation seems to point to the `H` itself.

So we really need more info from you:

1. More code, specifically the declaration of `NPOP`
2. Compiler version and -options

Comment: this seems to me to be a quite different error.  It does illustrate for the op the amount of code he should post though

Comment: Different compilers have slightly different error messages for the same syntax errors. In fact, when I tried with the Intel fortran compiler (even with `-warn all`) it didn't even give me any warning or error at all. So it might still be this error, just that his compiler complains about it in a slightly different way.